# Как "вынести" методы объектов в отдельный поток?

Tags: алгоритм, delphi, многопоточность, delphi-7

Пишу программу-эмулятор работы приборов (сразу нескольких). Обмен данных "происходит" условно по сети RS-485, т.е. программа подключается к сети и добавляет в сеть "виртуальные приборы". Реализовано это так:
1. Есть объект "шина данных". По сути контейнер объектов одного типа. Получая от одного объекта Send делает рассылку по всем остальным.
2. Объекты шины. Могут иметь разный функционал, но имплементируют один базовый интерфейс с функцией Receive (прием данных от шины).
Объекты шины есть двух типов: "виртуальное устройство" - (на основе полученных данных делает расчет и "отправляет" результат в "шину"), "источник данных" (например, объект открывает COM-порт, или TCP, или еще какой, и перебрасывает полученные данные в "шину", а из шины обратно в порт). Ограничение на количество объектов "шины" любого типа отсутствует (т.е. тех же COM-портов может быть 10).

Так вот. Работает все отлично. Но хотелось бы все это вынести в отдельный поток. Для чего это нужно - все объекты "инициируют" события (TNotifyEvent), например OnDataReceive, OnChanged и т.п. Обработка (визуальное отражение сопутствующей информации в окне программы) этих событий может занимать "долгое" время (критичное для эмуляции). Из-за чего мастер-устройство (реальное устройство на шине RS-485) "теряет" виртуальные устройства.

Полностью реализацию не могу представить (следовательно и реализовать, не зная что конкретно делать). Видится это так:
- Создаем объект "шину"
- Создаем-Добавляем на "шину" нужные объекты
- Запускаем поток (какой-нибудь метод шины "RunEmulation"), запускаются объекты "источники данных".
- Все данные от "источников" направляются в поток эмуляции, происходит рассылка по адресатам, обработка.
- В случае "инициации" события шине отправляется PostMessage с необходимой информацией и шина уже вызывает в основном потоке OnDataReceive, OnChanged и т.п. (тогда сообщения встанут в очередь, и пользовательская обработка не повлияет на работу потока эмуляции)

Как-то так. Может кто решал подобную задачу или просто есть мысли по правильному подходу в реализации

Comment: На самом деле, вы всё корректно описали: поток TBus (шина) инициализирует пасынков TDevice, а затем "дремлет" (фактически делает Sleep по таймеру или WaitForSIngle/MultipleObjects - тут уже конкретно нужно смотреть, как часто и в какой массе идут события). В зависимости от идеологии, вы затем либо напрямую синхронизируете событие, либо передаёте его по цепочке в очередь

Comment: Если эмулирую Мастер-устройство, то, соответственно, запросы идут с заданным мной интервалом. Но вот Мастер "в железе" шлет запросы непрерывным потоком с ожиданием ответа в миллисекунду (в реальности и того меньше), что и наводит на мысль о разграничении - обработка запросов в одном потоке, визуализация - в другом (тут уж временные рамки не критичны).

Comment: Так часто? Т.е. могу прилетать с частотой раз в 0.1 мс? Это уже критично: фактически, у вас есть всего лишь 200 с чем-то тактов процессора на обработку события. Как-то мало.

Comment: Да, так часто. Мастер устройство опрашивает поочередно (циклично) адресно 255 устройств, те в свою очередь сообщают об изменениях (т.е. перерасчет происходит только по действиям пользователя) и сообщают Мастеру результат перерасчета. Это все происходит достаточно быстро. Загвоздка в том, что мастер, получив новые данные от устройства, сообщает этому устройству о некорректности "ввода". Тогда устройство вызывает пользовательский метод. И если пользователь просто правит ошибку - все ок. Но если пользователю выводится Showmessage, то и появляется проблема, требующая вынести это в отдельный поток.

Comment: Вы правильно рассуждаете. Каждое ваше устройство и шина должны работать каждое в своем потоке. А уведомление пользователя о событиях должно быть через **PostMessage** в окно основного потока. А вот взаимодействие устройств и шины нужно делать через очередь команд и события, а не через PostMessage. PostMessage предполагает наличие окна, в которое его можно отправить, а его у потоков нет. Зачем вам еще к потокам прикручивать виртуальные окна?

Comment: Ну по большому счету на шине не может быть устройств с двумя одинаковыми адресами, т.е. по сути шина выбирает кем обработать сообщение. Не вижу смысла каждому выделять поток. Насчет окон - у шины и так есть виртуальное окно для функций таймеров, так что практически все есть. Я не могу сообразить как организовать доступ (как лучше синхронизировать потоки) к устройствам из основного потока для пользователя (изменение свойств, добавление/ удаление устройств). В общем, иду в правильном направлении, нужно с матчастью разобраться. Всем спасибо большое! Буду рад доп.коментариям.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем. Получилось следующее:
1) Поток для обработки сообщений:

```
TEmulatorThread = class(TThread)
private
  FOwnerHandle: THandle;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
  property OwnerHandle: THandle read FOwnerHandle;
public
  constructor Create(OwnerHandle: THandle);
end;

constructor TEmulatorThread.Create(OwnerHandle: THandle);
begin
  FOwnerHandle := OwnerHandle;
  inherited Create(False);
end;

procedure TEmulatorThread.Execute;
var
  msg: TMsg;
begin
  with TDataBus.Create(OwnerHandle) do
  try
    while not Terminated do
    begin
      try
        while PeekMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) do
          if msg.message = WM_TERMINATE then
            Terminate
          else
            DispatchMessage(msg);
        if not Terminated then
          WaitMessage;
      except
        PostMessage(OwnerHandle, WM_EXCEPTION, Integer(AcquireExceptionObject), 0);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

2) Сам эмулятор (приемник сообщений от шины данных):

```
constructor TEmulator.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FDataBus := nil;
  FWindowHandle := AllocateHWnd(WindowProc);
  FThread := TEmulatorThread.Create(FWindowHandle);
end;

destructor TEmulator.Destroy;
begin
  PostThreadMessage(FThread.ThreadID, WM_TERMINATE, 0, 0);
  FThread.WaitFor;
  FThread.Free;
  DeallocateHWnd(FWindowHandle);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TEmulator.WindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  with Message do
    case msg of
      WM_DATABUS_NOTIFY:
        case WParam of
          DB_CREATED:
            FDataBus := TDataBus(LParam);
          DB_DESTROYING:
            FDataBus := nil;
          DB_OBJECT_ADDED:
            ;
          DB_OBJECT_DELETED:
            ;
        end;
      WM_OBJECT_NOTIFY:
        ;
      WM_EXCEPTION:
        begin
          raise Exception(WParam);
        end;
    else
      DefWindowProc(FWindowHandle, msg, WParam, LParam);
    end;
end;
```

3) Шина данных (оповещение эмулятора):

```
procedure TBONDataBus.AfterConstruction;
begin
  PostMessage(FOwnerHandle, WM_DATABUS_NOTIFY, DB_CREATED, Integer(Self));
end;

procedure TBONDataBus.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  PostMessage(FOwnerHandle, WM_DATABUS_NOTIFY, DB_DESTROYING, 0);
  inherited;
end;
```

Все гетеры/сетеры объектов в потоке "прикрыты" критическими секциями.